# Apache ProxyPass: standalone vs location tag?

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

How do these two code blocks differ?

```
ProxyPass /app http://10.0.0.10/blah
ProxyPassReverse /app http://10.0.0.10/blah
```

versus

```
<Location /app>
    ProxyPass http://10.0.0.10/blah
    ProxyPassReverse http://10.0.0.10/blah
</Location>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the `Location` Directive is the preferred method to use. The alternative syntax of `Proxypass` like this `ProxyPass /app http://10.0.0.10/blah` can have performance impact when there are many. However depending on your need the alternative syntax might be better.

From the documentation:

> The following alternative syntax is possible, however it can carry a
>   performance penalty when present in very large numbers. The advantage
>   of the below syntax is that it allows for dynamic control via the
>   Balancer Manager interface:

```
ProxyPass "/mirror/foo/" "http://backend.example.com/"
```

Please have a look at the documentation for more info.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass

Answer (score 2):

It's a stylistic difference only, there's no functional difference.  If you started adding more options that apply only to /app you might find the latter more straightforward as they'd all live in the Location container.